# function returning before await function

Tags: node.js, typescript, hapi

im trying to write a function that updates shopping cart which given products info and give user the updated shopping cart, however when I call this function, database is updating but response is not.

**Code**

```
export const addToCart: Hapi.Lifecycle.Method = async (request, h, err) => {
  const payload: ProductIdPayload = <ProductIdPayload>request.payload;
  const userId: string = <string>request.auth.credentials._id;
  try {
    const [shoppingCart, product] = await Promise.all([
      ShoppingCartModel.findOne({ userId: userId }),
      ProductModel.findById(payload.productId),
    ]);
    if (product) {
      console.log(product);
      if (shoppingCart) {
        
        
        await shoppingCart.updateOne({
          $push: { productIds: payload.productId },
          $inc: { totalValue: product.price },
        });

        //above line updates database but below command returns non-updated shopping cart

        return h.response({
          shoppingCart: shoppingCart,
        });
      } else {
        
        const newShoppingCart = new ShoppingCartModel({
          userId: userId,
          productIds: [payload.productId],
          totalValue: product.price,
        });
        console.log(newShoppingCart)
        await newShoppingCart.save();
        return h.response({ shoppingCart: newShoppingCart });
      }
    } else {
      const error = Boom.notFound("Product Not Found");
      return error;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error();
  }
};
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: What does "response not updating" mean?  What exactly  do you observe?  What exactly do you expect to see?

Comment: for example im adding products price to totalValue, but it returns totalValue without added price

Comment: well I forgot to implement it, so focused to problem I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```js
const updatedShoppingCart = await shoppingCart.updateOne({
          $push: { productIds: payload.productId },
          $inc: { totalValue: product.price },
        });

return h.response({
          shoppingCart: updatedShoppingCart,
        });
```

If the above solution doesn't work for you use `findOneAndUpdate` function on the Model and pass `{new: true}` in the options.